# Comparing a column in an array to a set of values and returning another set of values from the second column with the corresponding indices

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an array with 2 columns (x, y).
I need to find values in the y column matching some other set of numbers, say [0.5, 0.5, 0.99] and return the values from the x column with the same indices into a new variable.

```
x=np.linspace(50,70,20)
y=np.linspace(0,1,20)
c=np.zeros((2,len(x)))
x=np.around(x,3)
y=np.around(y,3)
for ii, (left, right) in enumerate(zip(x[1:], y[1:])):
    print(left, right)
    c[0, ii] = left
    c[1, ii] = right
q=[0.05,0.5,0.99]
```

So I need to compare c[1,:] to q and then return the values from c[0,:] with the corresponding indices. 
I tried `for` and `enumerate` but I can't figure out whether I need to use iterator once or twice (for c and q). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.nonzero` to find the values of `q` in `y`.
The question is what is the expected behaviour if the value is not present in `y`.
Right now, the values for this case are `-1'.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.linspace(50, 70, n)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
x = np.around(x, 2)
y = np.around(y, 2)
q = [0.05, 0.50, 0.99]

res = np.full((len(q), 2), -1)
for i, qq in enumerate(q):
    j = np.nonzero(y == qq)[0]
    if np.size(j) == 1:
        res[i] = (j, x[j])

res 
#      index, value
# array([[ 5, 51],
#        [-1, -1],
#        [98, 69]])
```